# ActiveAdmin throws undefined method `stringify_keys'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activeadmin

I am Using ActiveAdmin 0.4.1 with Rails 3.2.1. 
In a plain rails app I create a new model via scaffolding and set it up as a resource for ActiveAdmin. When I try to create a new entity of my mode using the ActiveAdmin backend I get

```
undefined method `stringify_keys' for "new":String
```

without any application traces. Only the framework trace:

```
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:69:in `assign_attributes'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/base.rb:495:in `initialize'
inherited_resources (1.3.0) lib/inherited_resources/base_helpers.rb:52:in `new'
inherited_resources (1.3.0) lib/inherited_resources/base_helpers.rb:52:in `build_resource'
activeadmin (0.4.1) lib/active_admin/resource_controller/callbacks.rb:15:in `build_resource'
- snip -
```

What could be a possible solution to this?

Comment: Same happens when I create an entity manually from the console and then try to save it: undefined method `stringify_keys' for "update":String

Comment: And further exploring: The problem also persits with the version 0.4.2 of ActiveAdmin

Answer (score 0):

Check the name of the model and make sure you are not using a special word for it.

This happened to me when I named my model 'Action'.